# PeopleSoft: A SQL error occured. Please consult your system log for details

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

While clicking HTML link on my PS Query, I get the error: A SQL error occured. Please consult your system log for details. I want to know what the cause of this error, and if its my PS Query, since it's very straight forward. See SQL below:

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.ACAD_CAREER, A.STDNT_CAR_NBR, A.ADM_APPL_NBR, 
A.INSTITUTION, A.SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT
  FROM PS_SAD_PB_CAS A, PS_ADM_APPL_PROG B, PS_ADM_MAINT_SCTY B1, 
PS_SCC_PS_ADMA_BND C, PS_ADM_APPL_SCTY C1 
  WHERE ( B.EMPLID = B1.EMPLID 
    AND B.ACAD_CAREER = B1.ACAD_CAREER 
    AND B.STDNT_CAR_NBR = B1.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
    AND B.ADM_APPL_NBR = B1.ADM_APPL_NBR 
    AND B.APPL_PROG_NBR = B1.APPL_PROG_NBR 
    AND C.EMPLID = C1.EMPLID 
    AND C.ACAD_CAREER = C1.ACAD_CAREER 
    AND C.ADM_APPL_NBR = C1.ADM_APPL_NBR 
    AND C.INSTITUTION = C1.INSTITUTION 
    AND ( A.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_SAD_PB_CAS A_ED 
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
          AND A.INSTITUTION = A_ED.INSTITUTION 
          AND A.SAD_PB_REC_TYPE = A_ED.SAD_PB_REC_TYPE 
          AND A.ACAD_CAREER = A_ED.ACAD_CAREER 
          AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = A_ED.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
          AND A.SAD_PB_REC_NUMBER = A_ED.SAD_PB_REC_NUMBER 
          AND A.ADM_APPL_NBR = A_ED.ADM_APPL_NBR 
          AND A.APPL_PROG_NBR = A_ED.APPL_PROG_NBR 
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
    AND A.EFFSEQ = 
        (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_SAD_PB_CAS A_ES 
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID 
          AND A.INSTITUTION = A_ES.INSTITUTION 
          AND A.SAD_PB_REC_TYPE = A_ES.SAD_PB_REC_TYPE 
          AND A.ACAD_CAREER = A_ES.ACAD_CAREER 
          AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = A_ES.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
          AND A.SAD_PB_REC_NUMBER = A_ES.SAD_PB_REC_NUMBER 
          AND A.ADM_APPL_NBR = A_ES.ADM_APPL_NBR 
          AND A.APPL_PROG_NBR = A_ES.APPL_PROG_NBR 
          AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT) 
     AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
     AND A.ACAD_CAREER = B.ACAD_CAREER 
     AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = B.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
     AND A.ADM_APPL_NBR = B.ADM_APPL_NBR 
     AND A.APPL_PROG_NBR = B.APPL_PROG_NBR 
     AND B.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ADM_APPL_PROG B_ED 
        WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID 
          AND B.ACAD_CAREER = B_ED.ACAD_CAREER 
          AND B.STDNT_CAR_NBR = B_ED.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
          AND B.ADM_APPL_NBR = B_ED.ADM_APPL_NBR 
          AND B.APPL_PROG_NBR = B_ED.APPL_PROG_NBR 
          AND B_ED.EFFDT <= A.EFFDT) 
    AND B.EFFSEQ = 
        (SELECT MAX(B_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_ADM_APPL_PROG B_ES 
        WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ES.EMPLID 
           AND B.ACAD_CAREER = B_ES.ACAD_CAREER 
           AND B.STDNT_CAR_NBR = B_ES.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
           AND B.ADM_APPL_NBR = B_ES.ADM_APPL_NBR 
           AND B.APPL_PROG_NBR = B_ES.APPL_PROG_NBR 
           AND B.EFFDT = B_ES.EFFDT) 
     AND A.EMPLID = C.EMPLID 
     AND A.INSTITUTION = C.INSTITUTION 
     AND A.ACAD_CAREER = C.ACAD_CAREER 
     AND A.STDNT_CAR_NBR = C.STDNT_CAR_NBR 
     AND A.ADM_APPL_NBR = C.ADM_APPL_NBR 
     AND to_date( A.SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT,'DD-MON-YY') = to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY') 
     AND A.SAD_PB_CAS_STATUS IN ('ASG','USD') ));
```

Can anyone help me out with this error? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you consult your system log for details?

Comment: That's another problem, since I can't seem to find the navigation for the system log. There is another team that handles that and they are out of office, so I either have to find it manually across folders or try catching anything bad on my query.

Comment: The syntax looks correct, but we don't know the error message, the table structure or the data in your tables; as far as we know, maybe you're querying not existing tables... as is, it's really hard to answer this question

Comment: What module? Looks like maybe Campus Solutions? What version? How old is the query? It could be that the table structure changed in a bundle or something.

Comment: It would be nice to know which is the error... Can you access the DB using SQL plus or SQL Developer and execute the SQL ? You should get an ORA-nnn error code, anyway take a look at the tabs chars with an advanced text editor... Sometimes they seems to be spaces but the query parser is not seeing them at all so is better to be sure when you build a custom SQL for any reporting tool that there is at least one space left at the end of each row before the CRLF

Comment: Misspelling *'occurred'* is a fine old IT tradition. Good to see it being upheld :)

Comment: `to_date(a.sad_pb_cas_statdt,'DD-MON-YY') = to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')` is wrong. `sysdate` is already a date (and probably so is `sad_pb_cas_statdt`), so applying any character function to it is asking for trouble. Can you change it to `and a.sad_pb_cas_statdt >= trunc(sysdate) and a.sad_pb_cas_statdt < trunc(sysdate) +1`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, Thanks man! This did solve it for me. How do i make your comment the answer?

Comment: Sure. By the way, how is `PS_SAD_PB_CAS.SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT` defined in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part looks wrong:

```
to_date(a.sad_pb_cas_statdt,'DD-MON-YY') = to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')
```

`sysdate` is already a date (and probably so is `sad_pb_cas_statdt`), so applying any character function to it is asking for trouble. If `nls_date_format` is set to anything that is not compatible with the specified format `'DD-MON-YY'`, it will fail. (For example, you will get away with `'DD-MON-RRRR'`, but not `YYYY-MM-DD`.)

Try changing it to:

```
a.sad_pb_cas_statdt >= trunc(sysdate) and a.sad_pb_cas_statdt < trunc(sysdate) +1
```

or

```
a.sad_pb_cas_statdt between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate) + interval '86399' second
```